# How to read an entire file as bytes and set it to a variable in Python?

Tags: python

How do I get a file from my computer and read it as pure bytes, without it capping at 64kb?

I tried to do

```
filee = open(filepath, mode='rb')
filedata = filee.read(os.path.getsize(filepath))
print(filedata)
```

and i wanted it to set every byte in filee to filedata, to then be printed. Instead, it only printed a portion of the file, 64kb to be exact.

Comment: The effect of passing an argument to `read()` is to **limit** the amount of data that is read.  If you want to read the whole file, why are you passing an argument to `read()` at all?

Comment: And what is `command`?  How do you expect us to help when you post incomplete code?

Comment: i changed the variables in the code to make it easier to read. I meant to change command to filepath, but i messed up. Ill edit the code. Me putting os.path.getsize(filepath) was a desperate attempt to get it to work.

Comment: How do you know that `print(filedata)` printed exactly 64k?  Did you actually count?

Comment: The issue was not in that code, and the issue was something else entirely, so I am sorry. The issue, atleast I think, is in the twisted module which im using. It printed the right code in the client, and it printed the end of the right code in the server, so i thought they printed the same thing, meaning twisted wasnt the issue. After doing a bit more testing, i realized that twisted was the issue due to the bytes being printed in the server was just the very last pieces of the actual bytes of the file. Essentially, i am silly and i was wrong about what the issue was, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. By default, `.read()` will have no limitation on size.

```
with open('path_to_your_file', 'rb') as file:
    here_are_the_bytes = file.read()
```

Comment: That unfortunately didnt work for me. I'm going to try to see if there are any other things in the code that couldve affected the bytes.

Comment: @eggbladder Could you explain _why_ it didn't work? Did you get an error? Could the file not be read at all? Did it hit the 64kb cap you mentioned?

What files are you trying to read?

Comment: Apologies. First question here.
It still hit the 64kb cap, but after doing a bit more tests and such, i realized it was an issue with the twisted module, and not necessarily with the method of reading the bytes itself. I sent the code I thought would be relevant but the issue wasnt even in that code, and it was in an entirely different piece of code using a different module. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

If you express the filepath as a [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) object, you can simply call [`Path.read_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_bytes):

```
from pathlib import Path

filepath = Path("some/file/path")

data = filepath.read_bytes()
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work. I get the same result from that as i do with the code in the question.